# Can't horizontally align Material-UI Autocomplete & Material-UI FormControl

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image: horizontally_align]

Can't horizontally align Material-UI Autocomplete & Material-UI FormControl. I don't know what happened. When I import or write code for autocomplete then I got stuck into this. I need horizontally align the way FormControl and the Button is.
**codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-fast-fenv9?file=/src/Account.js:2364-2370

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container, Grid, TextField,
  FormControl, InputLabel, Select,
  MenuItem, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { createRef } from "react";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  mR: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(3)
  },

  formControl: {
    minWidth: 180,
    marginRight: theme.spacing(3)
  }
});

class Account extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      labelWidth: 0
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.inputLabel = createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ labelWidth: this.inputLabel.current.offsetWidth });
  }

  handleChange = (event) => this.setState({ age: event.target.value });

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const top100Films = [
      { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
      { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 }
    ];
    const { age, labelWidth } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
              <Autocomplete
                options={top100Films}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                style={{ maxWidth: 180 }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Account Name"
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                )}
                color="primary"
                size="small"
                autoFocus
              />

              <FormControl
                className={classes.formControl}
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
              >
                <InputLabel ref={this.inputLabel}>Age</InputLabel>
                <Select value={age} labelWidth={labelWidth}>
                  <MenuItem value="">
                    <em>None</em>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>

              <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Account);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap Autocomplete , Formcontrol , Button with :

```
 <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={4} lg={4} xl={4}>

    // Code

 </Grid>
```

This will divide it into 3 columns. (12 grid layout).

Also please correct the lablewidth code. Select box will overflow in small screen case.

Comment: Also I checked Autocomplete CSS is not being applied , So display block is enabled. Other two are working fine because display : inline-flex property is being enabled in MUI-root class.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the each of them using the `<Grid item xs>...</Grid>`

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Container>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Autocomplete
            options={top100Films}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
            style={{ maxWidth: 180 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Account Name"
                variant="outlined"
              />
            )}
            color="primary"
            size="small"
            autoFocus
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <FormControl
            className={classes.formControl}
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
          >
            <InputLabel ref={this.inputLabel}>Age</InputLabel>
            <Select value={age} labelWidth={labelWidth}>
              <MenuItem value="">
                <em>None</em>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  </React.Fragment>
```